# How to run same job parallel with different parameters for each run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a build job and a test job parameters.

I want to be after the build job, simultaneously run test job with one parameter and the same test job with different parameters in parallel execution.

```
            build job  
               |  
              / \  
     test job    test job
```

with one params    with other params
            |             |
How to accomplish this and whether it is possible to perform without having to write your own plugin?

Comment: use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin in the `build job`, set `execute concurrent builds if necessary` in the `test job`.

Comment: kindly, can you tell me how to configure exactly , so that i can acheive the above thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 We can do  something like this


    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();

    for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++) {
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("TmpSuite" + i);
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("TmpTest" + i);
        test.setParallel(ParallelMode.CLASSES);
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("first-name", valueList.get(i));
        test.setParameters(parameters);
        List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
        classes.add(new XmlClass("TestClass1"));
        classes.add(new XmlClass("TestClass2"));
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
        suites.add(suite);
    }

    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(5);
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.run();
```